# Angular template not showing in rails app

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add angular to my current rails app so I started researching here at http://angular-rails.com/.
Everything was going swimmingly until I tried to route a Angular call to load a template. For whatever reason, I get nothing when I load the page. I'm not sure what I am missing, and I'm sure it's something simple.

I created a simple controller to test out Angular with and created a route to the index controller method. Then in my views/angular_test/index.html.erb file I created a link to my ng-app and my ng-view like so:

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
    <div class="view-container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my app.coffee I created the app and configured the controller and the routeProvider:

```
testApp = angular.module('testApp',[
  'templates',
  'ngRoute',
  'controllers',
])

testApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  ($routeProvider)->
    $routeProvider
      .when('/testangular',
        templateUrl:"testangular.html",
        controller:"TestCtrl"
        )
])

controllers = angular.module('controllers',[])
controllers.controller("TestCtrl", [ '$scope',
  ($scope) ->
])
```

This all seems to be working, as in I get no errors in my rails server log. Or in the network logs in Chrome. Is there something simple that I'm missing here? Where do I start troubleshooting this?

For reference here are the contents of my Gemfile

```
...
gem 'bower-rails'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
group :development, :test do
   gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
   gem 'sqlite3'
   gem 'minitest'
   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
...
```

And my Bowerfile

```
asset 'angular'
asset 'angular-route'
asset 'bootstrap-sass-official'
```

I appreciate the help and I apologize for such a long post.

**Edit 1**
I'm just trying to demo this out before I start spending the time actually designing the page so right now I should just see a `<h1>This should be showing in my view</h1>` wrapped in my applications html page.

The URL I'm trying to view isn't the root url, but localhost:3000/testangular.

Comment: If you're okay with just cutting the Gordian Knot and starting over, I wrote [another Angular/Rails tutorial](http://www.angularonrails.com/ruby-on-rails-angularjs-single-page-application/) that I think is a little easier to follow.

Comment: I also have a few questions about this particular issue: What are you expecting to see when you load the page? What's the URL you're visiting? Is it the root URL? If you're expecting to see a certain template, can we see the content of that template?

Comment: @JasonSwett I don't mind 'cutting the Gordian Knot' as you put it, since I'm just starting to add Angular into my application. I'll take a look at your tutorial and give it a try. Also, I'll update the question with the answers to your questions

Comment: Do you have HTML5 pushState enabled? If not, maybe try `localhost:3000/#/testangular` instead of `localhost:3000/testangular`.

Comment: I gave that a try and still nothing. I'm wondering, is it possible that Rails and Angular are competing for the routes?

Comment: I suppose so. Maybe you could look at the dev log, refresh the page and see what route the log says you're hitting.